# Can we create a table using spark.sql api from the IDE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm on IntelliJ and my spark session looks like this -

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Spark SQL")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "src/main/resources/warehouse") //to create a user-defined warehouse for storing tables
    .config("spark.network.timeout"  , "10000000s")//to avoid Heartbeat exception
    .getOrCreate()
```

While I can create a database using
     `spark.sql("create database newdb")`
    This creates a directory under `src/main/resources/warehouse`

However when I attempt to create a table using the same manner
`spark.sql("create table testing(id int, name string)")`, it fails

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT);;
'CreateTable `testing`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, ErrorIfExists
```

Thereafter, I did add `enableHiveSupport()` while creating spark session, but it also leads me to this exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT**
This is my sbt

```
name := "spark-essentials"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

val sparkVersion = "3.0.0-preview"
val vegasVersion = "0.3.11"
val postgresVersion = "42.2.2"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven",
  "Typesafe Simple Repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/maven-releases",
  "MavenRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
  // logging
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.4.1",
  // postgres for DB connectivity
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % postgresVersion

)
```

EDIT:

```
below is the stack trace
20:41:08 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
20:41:08 WARN  Hive:168 - Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:221)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager(SharedState.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$2(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager(SessionCatalog.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$6.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$6.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:607)
    at part4sql.SparkSql$.delayedEndpoint$part4sql$SparkSql$1(SparkSql.scala:29)
    at part4sql.SparkSql$delayedInit$body.apply(SparkSql.scala:7)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at part4sql.SparkSql$.main(SparkSql.scala:7)
    at part4sql.SparkSql.main(SparkSql.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:src/main/resources/warehouse
```

Comment: @mazaneicha Added the build file now.

Comment: @mazaneicha added the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line in the stacktrace --

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:src/main/resources/warehouse`

-- hints that the proper way to set `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` is to supply an absolute path for metastore directory, something like `file:///<project_root_dir>/src/main/resources/warehouse`.

Comment: okay, I'm gonna change that and give it a try. 
Meanwhile, the current value supplied over there does however create the database, but not the table. wonder why is that?

Comment: This answer works and it does create the database and table in the current Spark session!
On a side note, this also throws an exception - 

21:32:58 ERROR RetryingHMSHandler:159 - AlreadyExistsException(message:Database newdb2 already exists)
However, there is a bug raised for this - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23575

But the answer did the job! Thanks @mazaneicha :)

Answer (score 0):

try including /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml  or respective hive-site file while you submit spark.

Also you can try including below configuration when submitting spark job

--conf "spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive" \